# Dilema ao popular datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho um problema que nem sei de como chamar. Mas vou tentar expressar aqui esse problema. É o seguinte, fiz uma paginação no meu `datalist` com o seguinte código:

```
private void FillDados()
{
    // Preenche uma lista de objetos para servirem de dataSource do nosso repeater.
    //(Essa lista de objetos pode ser consumida por um dataset por exemplo) 
    RepositorioProdutos Rep_Produtos = new RepositorioProdutos(NHibernateHelper.GetSession());
    IList<HelpDesk.Dominio.Entidades.Produtos> listarprodutos = Rep_Produtos.ObterTodos();
    pagina = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["pagina"]);
    numeropaginas = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["numeropaginas"]);

    //Seta a fonte de dados do objeto de paginação como a nossa lista de objetos
    pgds.DataSource = listarprodutos;

    //Permite a paginação do objeto
    pgds.AllowPaging = true;

    //Seta a pagina atual do objeto como sendo nosso ViewState de pagina.
    pgds.CurrentPageIndex = pagina;

    //Seta a quantidade de registros por página
    pgds.PageSize = 32;

    lbtnAnt.Visible = !pgds.IsFirstPage;
    lbtnProx.Visible = !pgds.IsLastPage;

    //Seta a fonte de dados do repeater como o nosso objeto de paginação.

    DataList1.DataSource = pgds;
    DataList1.DataBind();

    ViewState["numeropaginas"] = numeropaginas;
    ViewState["pagina"] = pagina;

}
```

Está funcionando perfeitamente. Tenho dois *button links*: `Próximo` e `Anterior` apenas. A função de ir para a próxima pagina ficou assim:

```
protected void Proximo(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Vai para a próxima página        
    pagina = Convert.ToInt16(ViewState["pagina"]);
    numeropaginas = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["numeropaginas"]);

    pagina = pagina + 1;
    if (numeropaginas < pgds.PageCount && pagina > (totalpaginas - numerop - 1))
    {
        numeropaginas = numeropaginas + 1;
    }

    //se forem as ultimas paginas
    else if (pagina >= (pgds.PageCount - ((totalpaginas + 1) / 2)))
    {
        numerop = totalpaginas - (pgds.PageCount - pagina);
    }
    else
    {
        numerop = numerop + 1;
    }
    ViewState["pagina"] = pagina;
    ViewState["numeropaginas"] = numeropaginas;
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPesquisar.Text))
    {
        FillDados();
    }
}
```

Como eu disse acima, funciona bem. O código acima busca todos produtos na minha base de dados e mostra em um `datalist`. Quando clico em `Próximo`, ele busca todos novamente e mostra a segunda pagina de todos os produtos.

Agora vejam o código abaixo:

```
protected void dtlCategoria_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).CommandName == "categoria")
    {
        IDictionary<String, Object> Param = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
        IList<HelpDesk.Dominio.Entidades.Produtos> listarprodutos;
        Int64 IDCategoria = Int64.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        Param.Add("Categoria.ID", IDCategoria);
        listarprodutos = Repositorio.ObterPorParametros(Param);

        DataList1.DataSource = listarprodutos;
        DataList1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

O código acima dispara ao clicar em um link que esta em um segundo `datalist`, ele filtra pela categoria e mostra no primeiro `datalist`, que também filtra corretamente. Meu problema então foi o *button link* de `Próximo` e `Anterior`. Depois que eu clico em *categoria* e depois de gerado o filtro, ao clicar no `Próximo` por exemplo, ele vai a pagina seguinte porém mostrando todos os produtos novamente, ignorando o filtro que fiz anteriormente.

Eu gostaria que ao eu clicar em uma categoria ele filtra de acordo com o mesmo, e se tiver uma segunda página daquela categoria ele mostra apenas os produtos daquela categoria, e não mostrar todos novamente como está acontecendo.

Bom, tentei explicar, espero que tenham entendido! Não sei como fazer para minha ideia funcionar, alguém pode me ajudar a chegar em uma solução?

Comment: `ItemCommand` não é chamado quando você clica em "Próximo" ou "Anterior". Que tal isolar o filtro em uma função e colocar uma chamada a esta função onde já se sabe que os eventos serão chamados?

Comment: **Vote hoje! Vote amanhã! Vote sempre! vote consciente!** O seu voto é muito importante para nossa comunidade, contribua conosco e ajude a tornar a Stack Overflow em Português(SOpt) cada vez maior. Você pode saber mais em: [**Vote cedo, vote frequentemente**](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/159/vote-cedo-vote-frequentemente)

Answer (score 1):

Ao clicar em uma página (provocando um postback) você precisa manter o status dos filtros que você selecionou antes visto que o http não mantem estado. Existem várias formas de fazer isso que envolvem analisar a sensibilidade da informação armazenada, você pode invocar os métodos do outro controle manualmente, passando os parametros de filtro assim que clicar na mudança de página.

Uma alternativa interessante pode ser manter esse status no ViewState:
https://www.codigofonte.net/dicas/dotnet/253_entendendo-o-que-e-viewstate

Não é uma boa prática um controle conhecer a implementação de outro, nem mesmo misturar os parametros de controle de um controle em métodos de outro. Geralmente, o ambiente onde o controle está passa os parametros de configuração para que o controle saiba como se comportar. Você pode fazer isso por metodos específicos ou atributos, é simples e isola a lógica em trechos específicos para configuração do comportamento dos componentes.